# Serve coordinates data from backend to render a 3D visualization in the frontend

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, data-structures

I have close to million points that I would like to create a 3D plot with. How can I efficiently transfer these coordinates to the frontend? We are planning to use D3.js to create our visualization.

The JSON request body is too large to send in one request.

Comment: Stream it? https://www.loginradius.com/blog/engineering/guest-post/http-streaming-with-nodejs-and-fetch-api/